# How do I display a bootstrap popover in autocomplete options in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to angularjs. I need to show a link on hover on autocomplete option, the 3 dots on left side [as below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtxcG.png)

And when I hover on the link(3 dots) I need to show a popover which is an html template.
I am not able to find a way to show the pop-over link.
Btw I am trying it with massautocomplete.
http://hakib.github.io/MassAutocomplete/

Below is how I Am creating the template -

```
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
 var user = users[i];
 if (user.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(q) !== -1 ||
     user.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(q) !== -1)
   results.push({
     value: user.name,
     // Pass the object as well. Can be any property name.
     obj: user,
     label: $sce.trustAsHtml(
       '<div class="row">' +
       ' <div class="col-xs-5">' +
       '  <i class="fa fa-user"></i>' +
       '  <strong>' + highlight(user.name,term) + '</strong>'+
       ' </div>' +
       ' <div class="col-xs-6 text-right text-muted">' +
       '  <small><a href="#">' + highlight(user.email,term) + '</a></small>' +
       ' </div>' +
         '<div  class="col-xs-1">' +
           '<a uib-popover-html="\'<b>test</b>\'" '+
            'popover-placement="right" popover-trigger="\'mouseenter\'">...</a>'+
       '</div>'+

       ' <div class="col-xs-12">' +
       '  <span class="text-muted">Joined</span>' +
          user.joined +
       ' </div>'
     )
   });
```

}

Any suggestion are welcome, I can use another autocomplete library as well if needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to modify the way you return the results to use the "passing objects" method as documented in the MassAutocomplete examples and then bind your ... to show a Bootstrap popover [Documented Here](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/popovers/) binding the content to a property on your object.

To angularise your bootstrap use AngularUI which has a specific popover implementation. [Documented Here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) See UI.Bootstrap.Popover.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am trying this way only. I am creating an html template with "uib-popover-html" element, but I am not getting the popover. Could you  please add some more details if possible. I am updating the question with how I am creating the template.

Comment: you'll need a button or some form of trigger for the popover that shows the content of the selected element.  In the docs they use the following : `<button uib-popover="{{dynamicPopover.content}}" popover-title="{{dynamicPopover.title}}" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Dynamic Popover</button>`

Comment: It works when I use it normally in html, but its not working inside the template for autocomplete. I think the pop-over html is not rendering angular content.

Comment: You won't be able to just add it to the Dom and get the popup functionality to work from the autosuggestion element, you'd be better having the button in the Dom from the start, and only making it visible when needed, and change the content and visibility when the suggestion is presented.

Comment: could you please provide an example, I need to show this button inside the autosuggest option ?

Comment: I'm on my mobile at the moment so a bit tricky to knock anything together.  The main point I was trying to make is that the JavaScript that binds the event handlers to the button to make it perform as a popover are all run as part of angular' loading routines. If you add the button to the Dom after this has all happened then you will need to call this js yourself. From memory, I think the documents show how to do this. If I do get back to my pc today I'll take a look, but what I would be doing is looking into adding a popover to the Dom after page load has occurred.